# Count the number of filled cells between empty cells in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below is an example of part of my dataframe:

```
col1     col2
items1    10
items1     5
items1     3
items1     2
items1   NaN
items1   NaN
items1   NaN
items1     4
items1     1
items1     1
items2     6
items2     4
items2     5
items2   NaN
items2   NaN
items2     2
items2     8
items2     7
items2     9
items2   NaN
...
```

I need for every unique value in column `col1` to count number of non empty cells between empty cells. I tried to use `groupby()` for grouping unique values in `col1` and `count()` to count values, but it count all non empty values for unique values in `col1`.

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':('items1','items1','items1','items1','items1','items1','items1','items1','items1','items1','items2','items2','items2','items2','items2','items2','items2','items2','items2','items2'),
                  'col2': (10, 5, 3, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4, 1, 1, 6, 4, 5, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 8, 7, 9, np.nan)})
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].count().reset_index()
```

The result looks like this:

```
      col1  col2
0   items1     7
1   items2     7
```

But I need to get the following:

```
      col1  col2
0   items1     4
1   items1     3
2   items2     3
3   items2     4
```

I would be grateful for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, PS:I did not add the `reset_index()` it will make the code tooo long..

```
df.groupby([df['col1'],df['col2'].isnull().diff().fillna(0).cumsum()])['col2'].count().replace(0,np.nan).dropna()
Out[885]: 
col1    col2
items1  0       4.0
        2       3.0
items2  2       3.0
        4       4.0
Name: col2, dtype: float64
```